# Bulk update information in Photos.app?

Tags: photos.app, macos

Is there a better way to update the photo metadata for pictures in the Photo.app rather than hitting "Get Info" on every single photo, such as weill a clever app or something? My goal is to add tags to my all of photos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get Info still works when selecting multiple photos (and only touches the fields you change so you won't accidentally overwrite stuff), and both shift and cmd do what you'd expect as far as selecting goes - same as iTunes basically. Plenty fast in my opinion.

For proper bulk library things (merging several massive libraries, etc) something like PowerPhotos is what you'd have to go with, though.